# Re-Arrange Correlation Matrix in R to get 1's on the Diagnols

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I have correlation matrix which got a bit scrambled. The 1's are out of place. I would like to get the 1's back on the diagonals.

The real matrix is 1k x 1k but here is a sample.

```
mat = structure(list(QQQ = c(0.61072455, 1, 0.793695176), SPY = c(0.699540765, 
0.793695176, 1), IWM = c(1, 0.61072455, 0.699540765), ticker = c("IWM", 
"QQQ", "SPY")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

print(mat)

        QQQ       SPY       IWM ticker
1 0.6107246 0.6995408 1.0000000    IWM
2 1.0000000 0.7936952 0.6107246    QQQ
3 0.7936952 1.0000000 0.6995408    SPY
```

I would like the output to be:

```
    QQQ       SPY       IWM       ticker
1 1.0000000 0.7936952 0.6107246    QQQ
2 0.7936952 1.0000000 0.6995408    SPY
3 0.6107246 0.6995408 1.0000000    IWM
```

It looks like I have to re-arrange the ticker column to match the column names. Something like sort(ticker, #by colnames) would be perfect. It looks like sort() can only arrange by ascending/descending order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `match` in `base R`

```
mat[order(match(mat$ticker, names(mat))),]
#       QQQ       SPY       IWM ticker
#2 1.0000000 0.7936952 0.6107246    QQQ
#3 0.7936952 1.0000000 0.6995408    SPY
#1 0.6107246 0.6995408 1.0000000    IWM
```

Comment: `mat[, c(mat$ticker, "ticker")]`

Answer (score 2):

You want to get the rows ordered in the same way as the columns. Using `dplyr`:

```
mat %>%
    mutate(order = match(ticker, colnames(mat))) %>%
    arrange(order)
```

Output (obviously you can now drop the `order` column):

```
        QQQ       SPY       IWM ticker order
1 1.0000000 0.7936952 0.6107246    QQQ     1
2 0.7936952 1.0000000 0.6995408    SPY     2
3 0.6107246 0.6995408 1.0000000    IWM     3
```

Comment: Marius Thanks you for your input!! I have decided to go with Akrun answer just because I don 't have to drop the column. But this was super helpful. Thanks for using dplyr!

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to search for the column index where `1` occurs for each row, something like:

```r
ind = apply(mat, 1, function (x) which (x == 1)
```

Which will give you a vector of column indices where the `1` occurs. Then, rearrange the matrix rows by (ascending) column index:

```r
mat[order (ind), ]
```

I'm on mobile so I haven't actually tested this.

**Edit** you are operating on a data frame, not a matrix. The same principle applies but you need to exclude the "ticker column in your `apply` statement:

```r
ind = apply(mat[, 1:3], 1, function (x) which (x == 1)
```

To be even safer, use `near` or `all.equal` instead of `==`, you should generally avoid testing floating point numbers for equality (although it often works out ok in R).

Comment: If there are any other correlations of 1 then this approach will become problematic.

Comment: @elin true, but then I question what logic was used to construct the "ticker" column in the first place since the same issue would be at play.